# Django SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, captcha, traceback

Good day. Creating a project https://github.com/LeonidPrice/advertisementboard with Django REST framework I got the following error when starting the server:
(All migrations are done)

```
 (board) D:\python_projects\board\board>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\python_projects\board\board\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python_projects\board\board\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\python_projects\board\board\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 558, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (captcha.recaptcha_test_key_error) RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY or RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY is making use of the Google test keys and will not behave as expected in a production environment     
        HINT: Update settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY and/or settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY. Alternatively this check can be ignored by adding `SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['captcha.recaptcha_test_key_error']` to your settings file.

WARNINGS:
main.AdditionalImage: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MainConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
main.AdvUser: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MainConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
main.Board: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MainConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
main.Comment: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MainConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
main.Rubric: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MainConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
main.SubRubric: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MainConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
main.SuperRubric: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
        HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the MainConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.

System check identified 8 issues (0 silenced).
```

Please tell me what is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Install the awesome django-recaptcha and follow the instructions. Make sure to at least add the settings below.

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'key'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = 'secret'
NOCAPTCHA = True

#Now you can simply add the captcha field to a form.

from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class ReCAPTCHAForm(forms.Form):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

It seems you forgot to add the settings RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY or RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY in the settings.py file.

You can find a whole explanation here [DJANGO](https://blog.bitlabstudio.com/using-recaptcha-with-django-1b7aea786ad6)